# Entity Framework - Code First doesn't load referenced object

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, code-first, ef-code-first

I have two simple classes generated by code first.

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

After saving Company in database I have Company (Id = 1 | name = "blah" | AddressId = 1) and its Address (Id = 1, Country = "Poland"). When I'm trying to load from my DbContext:

```
Company company = context.Companies.Find(id);
```

I get company with null Address property. What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using CTP5.)

Comment: Btw. don't use CTP5 there is already EF 4.1 RC which has "final" version of the API: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2dc5ddac-5a96-48b2-878d-b9f49d87569a

Comment: How did you access `Address`. There should be lazy loading triggered.

Comment: I have checked my versions. I have EntityFramework.dll runtime version v4.0.30319, and version 4.0.0.0. When I use nuget I get '
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
'EntityFramework 4.1.10311.0' already installed.
I-mo already has a reference to 'EntityFramework 4.1.10311.0'.'
It is strange and lazy load still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you turn off lazy loading or proxy creation?

Comment: Aaaa... I was sure that answer is not but in runtime it turned out that is true. I found somewhere that for tests I set LazyLoadingEnabled=false. Shame on me... Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
Company company = context.Companies.Include("Address").Find(id);
```

or with the new typed syntax:

```
Company company = context.Companies.Include(c => c.Address).Find(id);
```

This tells EF to eagerly load the `Address` entity as part of your `Company` entity.

It also seems you have repository layer on top of EF - make sure that your repository implementation supports `Include()` if that's the case.

Just for starters this is the implementation of `Include()` that Julia Lerman provides in "Programming Entity Framework" to support a unit-testable Repository pattern with POCOS (this version only works with the first syntax):

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Include<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string path)
{
    var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<TSource>;
    if (objectQuery != null)
    {
        return objectQuery.Include(path);
    }
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Or you can use more generic custom extension for includes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637