# EF CTP5 - IDbSet.Include

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5, entity-framework-4.1

I have a generic repository and I am having some trouble with the Include extension method. My repository looks like this:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> {
    private IDbSet<TEntity> _entitySet;

    /*
        some init code
    */

    public TEntity GetByKey(params object[] keys) {
        return _entitySet.Find(keys);
    }

    /*
        more db query methods
    */

    public IRepository<TEntity> Include(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector) {
        _entitySet = _entitySet.Include(selector) as IDbSet<TEntity>;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is supposed to be called something like this:

```
var blogRepository = new Repository<Blog>();
var blogEntry = blogRepository
    .Include(b => b.Posts)
    .Include(b => b.Someothercollection)
    .GetByKey(1);
```

The problem here is that when I cast the return value of Include in my repository to IDbSet<> I always get null. I must be doing something wrong but I am not sure what. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think I have just answered your question on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/596363b4-436e-43c9-a280-7f5ae63ba49f

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637 ?