# Ladislav Mrnka's advice to use Include

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to use Ladislav Mrnka's advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637) to use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SimTask.Data.EF4
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
            params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
            where T : class
        {
            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes.Aggregate(query,
                          (current, include) => current.Include(include));
            }

            return query;
        }

    }
}
```

But I get an error. The compiler doesn't recognize `current.Include`:

```
Error   7   'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\MySolution\MyProj.Data.EF4\Extensions.cs 19  57  MyProj.Data.EF4
```

I installed the ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b41c728e-9b4f-4331-a1a8-537d16c6acdf&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1) You need a reference (and `using`) to `System.Data.Entity`, that is where `Include` is defined:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

2) Your class should be marked `public` and `static`, otherwise you cant put an extension method in it:

```
public static class Extensions
{
```

**Edit:**

You also need to include EntityFramework in your project - if you expand references in your project you should see `EntityFramework`.

The easiest way to add it is via Nuget:

1.) Open the Package Manager Console (View | Other Windows | Package
    Manager Console)

2.) Type *Install-Package EntityFramework*

Comment: @Naor: Did you add a reference to EntityFramework to your project?

Comment: I have reference to System.Data.Entity. Doesn't it represents the entity framework?

Comment: @Naor: It represents EFv4. EFv4.1 are additional features to EFv4. You must reference both System.Data.Entity.dll and EntityFramework.dll (you will find it in installation directory of EFv4.1)