# Explicit loading of grandchild collections in EF 4.1

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Given the following model ...

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Grandchild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
}

public class Grandchild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

... we can **eager load** with `Include` a `Parent` with all `Children` and `Grandchildren` in one step like so:

```
context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children.Select(c => c.Grandchildren))
```

Is something similar possible for **explicit loading**?

The child collection can be explicitely loaded this way:

```
Parent parent = context.Parents.Find(parentId);
context.Entry(parent).Collection(p => p.Children).Load();
```

But trying to load the children in a similar way as with `Include` ...

```
context.Entry(parent)
    .Collection(p => p.Children.Select(c => c.Grandchildren)).Load();
```

... doesn't compile und the string overload of `Collection` ...

```
context.Entry(parent).Collection("Children.Grandchildren").Load();
```

... throws an exception ("...no dotted paths allowed...").

The only thing which I found working is to explicitely load the `Grandchildren` in a loop:

```
Parent parent = context.Parents.Find(parentId);
context.Entry(parent).Collection(p => p.Children).Load();
foreach (var child in parent.Children)
    context.Entry(child).Collection(c => c.GrandChildren).Load();
```

I am wondering if I missed something and if there is some other way to explicitely load the `GrandChildren` in one roundtrip.

Thanks for feedback in advance!

Comment: Did you try `Collection(...).Query().Include(...).Load()`? If it doesn't work as well I'm afraid that it is not supported. Generally `Load` is equivalent of handling `RelatedEnd.Load` from ObjectContext API.

Comment: @Ladislav: Please put this in an answer :) It works!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As I pointed in the comment you can try to get query for relation first, then add includes and execute loading. Something like:

```
context.Entry(parent)
       .Collection(p => p.Children)
       .Query()
       .Include(c => c.Grandchildren) // I'm not sure if you can include grandchild directly  
       .Load();
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I tried after your comment, and it works. It opens the question, if you could then also load "GrandGrandChildren" with `Include(...Select(...))` and so on. But I'd guess it will work too. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: I've just tested the code with your `IncludeMultiple` (instead of simple Include) from here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637) with "GrandGrandChildren" and "SomeReferenceInGrandChild" and it works too!

Comment: It should work because `Query()` returns `ObjectQuery` implementing `IQueryable` so it is EF query as any other only with some predefined condition.

Comment: Late to this thread, I know, but the `Load()` only covers entities specified _after_ the `Query()` (Grandchildren). But then a second SQL call is made to load the missing entity layer (Children). So you get 2 SQL calls, but everything ends up loaded.

To be fully explicit, use two calls, the first being:
`context.Entry(parent).Collection(p => p.Children).Load();`

Comment: I am super late to this party, but this still works in EF6