# How to brings the Entity Framework Include extention method to a Generic IQueryable<TSource>

Tags: entity-framework, methods, code-first

Here's the thing.

I have an interface, and I would to put the `Include` extension method, who belongs to *EntityFramework* library, to my `IRepository` layer wich dont needs to knows about *EntityFramework*.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Entities { get; }

    TEntity GetById(long id);
    TEntity Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(long id);
}
```

So I have the extension method:

```
public static class IncludeExtension 
{
    static IQueryable<TEntity> Include<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, 
        string path)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to implement it in this layer, and I would to send it to my EntityFramework (or whatever who will implement the IRepository) to deal with.

I need same to a Interface with a extension method.

Any light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but here are two EF-independent solutions if you or anyone else is still looking:

**1. Reflection-based Solution**

This solution is what the .NET Framework falls back to if the `IQueryable` does not cast to a `DbQuery` or `ObjectQuery`. Skip these casts (and the efficiency it provides) and you've decoupled the solution from Entity Framework.

```
public static class IncludeExtension  
{ 
    private static T QueryInclude<T>(T query, string path) 
    { 
        MethodInfo includeMethod = query.GetType().GetMethod("Include", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

        if ((includeMethod != null) && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(includeMethod.ReturnType))
        {
           return (T)includeMethod.Invoke(query, new object[] { path });
        }

        return query;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string path) where T : class
    {
        return QueryInclude(query, path);
    }

    // Add other Include overloads.
}
```

**2. Dyanmics-based Solution**

Here the `QueryInclude<T>` method uses the `dynamic` type to avoid reflection.

```
public static class IncludeExtension  
{ 
    private static T QueryInclude<T>(T query, string path) 
    { 
        dynamic querytWithIncludeMethod = query as dynamic;

        try
        {
            return (T)querytWithIncludeMethod.Include(path);
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException)
        {
            return query;
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string path) where T : class
    {
        return QueryInclude(query, path);
    }

    // Add other Include overloads.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Include` is leaky abstraction and it works only with Entity framework. EF 4.1 [already contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696395%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) `Include` over generic `IQueryable` but it internally only converts passed generic `IQueryable` to generic `ObjectQuery` or `DbQuery` and calls their `Include`.

Here is some example how to wrap that [include in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637) (repository implementation is dependent on EF so it can use `Include` provided by EF directly).

Comment: So, I just don't want depeding on EF. I'm trying to avoid references it in my client layer.

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework 5.0 they now provide an extension method to IQueryable to add the Include functionality.  You will just need to add a using "System.Data.Entity" in order to resolve the extension method.  For direct documentation go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)