# IQueryable<T>.Include(string path) not modifying query to include joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Using Entity Framework 5, I have a generic method that retrieves entities from my context with optional parameters to filter, include related entities, and set the order of results. When I pass the method a set of include properties, however, it never modifies the query with joins to include the related entities. Any ideas why my query isn't updating?

Method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    string includeProperties = "",
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
{        
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet.AsExpandable();

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query);
    }
    else
    {
        return query;
    }
}
```

Query before `foreach (var includeProperty...` that remains unchanged afterwards

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Pid] AS [Pid],     
[Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Extent1].[Creator] AS [Creator]
FROM [Administrator] AS [Extent1]}
```

**EDIT...More Info**

Originally I was using the following method call: `AdministratorDTO admin = unitOfWork.AdministratorComponent.GetByID(userPid);` on the following POCO class:

```
public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
{
    return dbSet.Find(id);
}

public class Administrator : IPrincipal
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    [Display(Name = "PID")]
    public string Pid { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string Creator { get; set; }

    ...

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And using AutoMapper to map to a DTO with the following configuration:

```
public class AdministratorDTO
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    [Display(Name = "PID")]
    public string Pid { get; set; }

    ...

    public string[] Roles { get; set; }

    public string[] Areas { get; set; }
}


public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
...
AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
}

public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ConfigureAdministratorMapping();
        ...
    }

    private static void ConfigureAdministratorMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Administrator, AdministratorDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Roles == null ? 
                    null : src.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToArray())) 
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Areas, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Areas == null ?
                    null : src.Areas.Select(a => a.Id).ToArray()));

        ...
    }
}

public class BusinessComponent<TEntity, TDto> 
    : IBusinessComponent<TEntity, TDto>
        where TEntity : class
        where TDto : class
{
    ...
    protected TDto Flatten(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TEntity, TDto>(entity);
    }
}
```

My understanding was that if I didn't mark the `Administrator`'s navigation properties (Areas and Roles) as `virtual` they would be eagerly loaded, but I kept getting an empty string[] in my DTO.

I looked at the TEntity parameter going into my `Flatten` method and Areas/Roles were `null` *before* I called `Map`, so I don't think it was something to do with AutoMapper.

Next I tried using the following method call:

```
AdministratorDTO admin = unitOfWork.AdministratorComponent
    .Get(filter: a => a.Pid == "csherman", includeProperties: "Roles, Areas")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Finally, just in case the `Include` was being ignored because the navigation properties were not `virtual`, I added the `virtual` keyword to both `Areas` and `Roles` on my `Administrator` class. When I did this, both the `GetByID` and the `Get(filter: ..., includeProperties: ...)` methods worked, thereby including the Areas/Roles in my TEntity `Flatten` parameter and populating the string arrays in my DTO.

Problem solved I suppose, but...

Question is, especially for the `GetById` method, why did it work with the `virtual` keyword but *not* without?

If EF actually factors in the projection from the time of the original method call, why would these entities be included?

Comment: Are you by any chance using projection? Calling .Select() on an IQueryable will result in an SQL projection, and it will just retrieve what you ask it for. In this case all Includes() will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my OP to include a more thorough (and very lengthy, sorry) explanation of what I was doing. It appears I was using projection in one of my methods, but it still looks like it works later when I made a change to my model. See above for more info...

Answer (score 2):

Includes don't work if you do any sort of projection after the include.

[Here's a post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) that deals with this and how to work around it.

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924386/if-i-select-from-an-iqueryable-then-the-include-is-lost) an SO question that deals with it as well.

EDIT: In response to your edit I tried looking around to see if I could find a reason why the `virtual` keyword would make your `Include` work but not work without it. I couldn't find anything in passing that would directly answer that.

Here's what I think is happening, though: The `virtual` keyword, on navigation properties, tells Entity Framework that this property should employ lazy loading. If there are times that you want to load them eagerly is when you would use `Include`. I think that that's what `Include` is built for. I think it tries to look specifically for `virtual` properties with that name, and when it can't find it, dies gracefully without exception. If you don't mark it as `virtual` I think the implementation of `Include` misses it completely. I base this guess on the fact that none of the articles that I've seen on `Include` mentioned it outside the context of lazy loading--which would mean using the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: Thank you much for making my comment an answer, kind Sir! And as a side node, despite your answer most likely being correct, it still is only guessing.

Comment: Sarcasm? How original. Let's see: 1) I posted *2 links* which mention that along with a **work around** for the problem, something you didn't mention. 2) If you look at the timestamp you'll hopefully realize that I was in the middle of writing this answer when you commented. It wasn't even a minute later.

Comment: Oh, and one other thing: Last time I checked, tables with names like `Administrator` tend to have more than just 3 fields in them. In which case OP *is* doing a projection, which would cause this problem.

Comment: Oh, and I flagged your comment. Good day.

Comment: @IronMan84 Thanks for taking a look at the edit. Everything I've read about EF concurs with what you said about `virtual`, and I figured the same: `Include` gracefully dies when the navigation property isn't `virtual` because it assumes it's already loaded. Why then `DbSet<TEntity>.Find` returns the navigation property when it's `virtual` and fails to return it when it's NOT `virtual` is beyond me at the moment. And this is occurring before I use AutoMapper to flatten TEntity.

Answer (score 0):

There's a serious problem with `IQueryable.Include`: the underlying object must be of type `ObjectQuery` or `DbQuery`, otherwise this method will not work!

> `Include` is leaky abstraction and it works only with Entity framework. EF 4.1 already contains `Include` over generic `IQueryable` but it internally only converts passed generic `IQueryable` to generic `ObjectQuery` or `DbQuery` and calls their `Include`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6791874/2444725

> When I pass the method a set of include properties, however, it never modifies the query with joins to include the related entities. Any ideas why my query isn't updating?

You seem to be using LinqKit:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet.AsExpandable();
```

Extension method `AsExpandable` gets `IQueryable` parameter and returns a new object of type `ExpandableQuery`, that decorates the original `ObjectQuery` or `DbQuery` object. Extension method `IQueryable.Include`, applied to `ExpandableQuery`, can't make the conversion and silently skips.

> why did it work with the virtual keyword but not without?

Virtual method has nothing to do with include. Instead it turns on lazy loading. It means that navigation properties are not loaded on the first request, but are loaded on separate requests when these properties are actually used.