# Using a params array of linq Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions

In EF, when you want to include a navigation property in the result of a query, you use `Include()`. Since some queries require calling this more than once, I tried to create a generic wrapper around this concept:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindAll<P>(params Expression<Func<T, P>>[] predicates) where P : class {
  var entities = AllEntities();
  foreach (var p in predicates) entities = entities.Include(p);
  return entities;
}
```

And call it as such:

```
var customers = FindAll(q => q.Orders, q => q.Invoices, q => q.Contacts);
```

Questions:

1. The function compiles, but when I call it: "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." What am I doing wrong?
2. If I get it to work, can I call `Include()` the first time: `var customers = FindAll(q => q.Orders, q => q.Invoices);` and then again later in a separate step: `customers = customers.Include(p => p.Invoices);` or will that result in poor performance such that I should do the includes in one go?

**EDIT:**
JonSkeet's answer is correct, of course, and yet [there is this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376637/1711500) which seems to do what I want. Not sure why it works however. Is it because of the `Aggregate()` function?

Comment: Would making it `Func<T, object>` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, I think you've got a problem - assuming that `q.Orders`, `q.Invoices` and `q.Contacts` return different types, you can't express what you *want* to happen. You probably *want* something like:

```
entities.Include<Parent, Order>(p => p.Order);
entities.Include<Parent, Invoice>(p => p.Invoices);
entities.Include<Parent, Contact>(p => p.Contacts);
```

... so you want a different value for `P` for each predicate. But you're calling a single method, providing a single type argument for `P`.

It's not clear that this is really giving you much benefit anyway... couldn't you just write:

```
var customers = AllEntities().Include(q => q.Orders)
                             .Include(q => q.Invoices)
                             .Include(q => q.Contacts);
```

I'd say that's clearer *and* it gets round the "multiple type parameters" problem.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing now, but its in a generic repository and I wanted to be able to specify which of those navigation properties to pull in together with a query; and of course different entities have different navigation properties. If there's no good way to do it I'll carry on using the normal approach.

Comment: @BobbyB: Do you understand may point about why your current approach can't work? What type argument would you *want* to use for `P`?

Comment: yes what I meant is that I'm currently doing it using your "alternative way" (in your second code block). The way I *wanted* to do it doesn't work for the exact reason you explained - `P` is multiple types i.e. `Orders`, `Invoices` and `Contacts`.

Comment: I agree with your comments, but how does it compare [to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5376637/1711500) which seems to do what I want? Not sure of the difference here?

Comment: @BobbyB: The difference is that that question only took `Expression<Func<T, object>>` expressions. I'm somewhat surprised it works at all, but if it helps you, that's fine. It doesn't change my point that the reason your version *isn't* working is that you're trying to take multiple `Func<T, P>` projections (not really predicates, btw) but with different `P` types, all in one call.

Comment: I'm also using expressions... see question's code. But you're right I was using `P` instead of `object`. So does *that* approach work because of the `object` type, or because of the use of `Aggregate()`?

Comment: @BobbyB: It works because all of the expressions can be converted to `Func<T, object>`, but there's no single `P` (other than `object` or perhaps some interface or base class) such that all of your expressions can be converted to `Func<T, P>`. It's not clear to me whether the `Aggregate` call in the other post was actually required - I suspect it was just a fancy way of doing a `foreach` loop really :)