# EF orderby / thenby combo extension method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I want to be able to apply combo `firstby / thenby` sorting as follows:

```
allOrders().sort(s => s.ProductName, s => s.OrderDate)
```

So using [this post as inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376637/1711500), I wrote this extension method, which compiles fine:

```
public static IQueryable<T> sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, params 
  Expression<Func<T, object>>[] predicates) where T : class 
{
  var sorted = entities.OrderBy(predicates[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < predicates.Length; i++)
    sorted = sorted.ThenBy(predicates[i]);

  return sorted;
}
```

And I also tried this succint version, which also compiles:

```
public static IQueryable<T> sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, params 
  Expression<Func<T, object>>[] predicates) where T : class
{
  return predicates.Skip(1).Aggregate(
    entities.OrderBy(predicates[0]),
    (aggregate, currentPredicate) => aggregate.ThenBy(currentPredicate));
}
```

However if I try sort by a `DateTime`, I get this exception:

> *Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*

What am I doing wrong? I am using EF5.

Comment: so you want to sort by  s.ProductName, and then by  s.OrderDate

Comment: yes in the order specified in the call to the extension method

Comment: Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486019/1300910

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you return a value type (such as `int` or `DateTime`) from a lambda expression that returns `object`, the compiler generates a `Box()` call to turn the value type into a boxed object.

The Entity Framework expression parser can't handle this box expression.
The only solution is to pass a strongly-typed lambda expression that returns the value type.

To do that, you can mis-use collection initializers:

```
public class OrderingCollection<TEntity> : IEnumerable {
    public void Add<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>) {
        ...
    }
}

public static IQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, 
                                    OrderingCollection<T> o) where T : class {
    ...
}


q = q.Sort(new OrderingCollection { s => s.ProductName, s => s.OrderDate });
```

Collection initializers allow you to use type inference with an arbitrary number of different type parameters.

Comment: this has less "noise" than the tuple idea, but it's a pity the calling code couldn't be simpler. Nice solution though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with `Func<T, object>`.  That means that you're going to return an object no matter what you're sorting on, and EF can't map that to a database column type.

The `OrderBy()` function takes both a `TSource` and a `TKey`, so you'd need to supply the key type for each sort, which quickly gets out of control (see [`Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386921.aspx)).

Comment: So the tuple's values would be the individual expressions?

Comment: Well, if you want to go with a Tuple directly, yes.  `.Sort(Tuple.Create(s => s.ProductName, s => s.OrderDate))` would pass a typed `Tuple` into your sort function.  But I don't know if there's a way to make that work with an arbitrary number of expressions.  I was using it more by way of example - you'd need `Sort<T, TKey>()`, `Sort<T, TKey1, TKey2>()`, Sort<T, TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>()`, and so on.