# Programmatically chain OrderBy/ThenBy using LINQ / Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a reporting interface where the end user gets to select multiple fields for the sort order of the returned report.  The problem I am having is that I can't really chain the OrderBy / ThenBy methods, since I'm iterating through a list of sort fields. I'm thinking something like this:

```
foreach (string sort in data.SortParams)
{
    switch (sort)
    {
        case "state":
            query = query.ThenBy(l => l.RegionCode);
            break;
        case "type":
            query = query.ThenBy(l => l.Type);
            break;
        case "color":
            query = query.ThenBy(l => l.Color);
            break;
        case "category":
            query = query.OrderBy(l => l.Category);
            break;
    }
}
```

(Note: I've removed the switch determining if this is the first sort item for simplicity's sake.)

Any thoughts on how to iterate through a collection to determine the sort order?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do what you want if you use an initial "seed" OrderBy:

**EDIT** you need to call `OrderBy` to create an `IOrderedEnumerable` (or `IOrderedQueryable`) first before attaching `ThenBy` clauses:

```
var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(l => 0);
foreach (string sort in data.SortParams)
{
    switch (sort)
    {
        case "state":
            orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(l => l.RegionCode);
            break;
        case "type":
            orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(l => l.Type);
            break;
        case "color":
            orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(l => l.Color);
            break;
        case "category":
            orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(l => l.Category);
            break;
    }
}
query = orderedQuery;  // cast back to original type.
```

If you want something more flexible check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Comment: Creative, but need to check if this impacts query performance. It might prevent index usage.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. At first I had the exact same code as above, however I was forced to choose a default column for the first `OrderBy()` -- I did not know I could put 0 there instead. The 0 will cause the ultimate SQL query to come out with an extra column that has value 0 for every row, then it sorts by that row, achieving the dummy sorting, then it applies all the columns in the chained `ThenBy()'s` that you added. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when calling `OrderBy(l => 0)`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/TZQ9g8Es)'s the `StackTrace`.

Comment: Apparently this is a [known bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10946) in EF Core, please vote / comment.

Answer (score 19):

I've created these extension methods to tackle an identical problem as stated in the question:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> AppendOrderBy<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
        => query.Expression.Type == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>)
        ? ((IOrderedQueryable<T>) query).ThenBy(keySelector)
        : query.OrderBy(keySelector);

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> AppendOrderByDescending<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
        => query.Expression.Type == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>)
            ? ((IOrderedQueryable<T>)query).ThenByDescending(keySelector)
            : query.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
}
```

The code in the question could then be refactored to:

```
foreach (string sort in data.SortParams)
{
    switch (sort)
    {
        case "state":
            query = query.AppendOrderBy(l => l.RegionCode);
            break;
        case "type":
            query = query.AppendOrderBy(l => l.Type);
            break;
        case "color":
            query = query.AppendOrderBy(l => l.Color);
            break;
        case "category":
            query = query.AppendOrderBy(l => l.Category);
            break;
    }
}
```

**REMARK** These extension methods only check the previous expression in the expression tree to determine wether to use `OrderBy` or `ThenBy`, no other expressions are allowed in-between. If you also want to tackle that, you'll have to walk through the complete tree which might just add that overhead you don't want :)

Comment: I had the same idea but did not know how to do it, thanks.It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;


abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public override string ToString() => $"Id: {Id}, Name: {Name}";
}

class OrderSpecification<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public bool IsDescending { get; private set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> Selector { get; private set; }
    public OrderSpecification(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector, bool isDescending = false)
    {
        Selector = selector;
        IsDescending = isDescending;
    }
}




static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, OrderSpecification<T>[] specs) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        if (specs.Length == 0)
            return query;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var spec in specs)
        {
            if (i++ == 0)
                query = spec.IsDescending ? query.OrderByDescending(spec.Selector) : query.OrderBy(spec.Selector);
            else
            {
                var temp = query as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
                query = spec.IsDescending ? temp!.ThenByDescending(spec.Selector) : temp!.ThenBy(spec.Selector);
            }
        }

        return query;
    }

}



class MyDatabase
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var products = new[]
        {
            new Product{ Id=4, Name="Cindy"},
            new Product{ Id=2, Name="Andy"},
            new Product{ Id=1, Name="Victor"},
            new Product{ Id=1, Name="Bobby"},
            new Product{ Id=3, Name="Austin"}
        }
        .AsQueryable();


        var output = products.Sort(new OrderSpecification<Product>[]
        {
            new OrderSpecification<Product>(p=>p.Id), // Order by Id first,
            new OrderSpecification<Product>(p=>p.Name, true), // then order by Name descendingly 
        });


        foreach (var p in output) Console.WriteLine(p);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

May be using all in one Linq query is not the best option from readability point of view. I would use IQueryable to construct your query in memory. Use similar sort of switch statement (but with IQueryable) and then in the end do .ToList (i.e. enumerate) to execute desired query at the server.

Comment: Thanks, but the `query` var here is in fact an IQueryable; the issue is with the OrderBy and ThenBy commands.. It seems as if the ThenBy can only be used when first chained to an OrderBy.