# How to generate a dynamic number of ThenBy clauses in a Specification

Tags: c#, linq

I'm building a Spec Evaluator which must consider multiple possible OrderBy, as in the next example:

```
if (spec.Order != null)
{
    var count = spec.Order.Count;

    if (count == 1)
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(spec.Order[0]);
    }
    else if (count == 2)
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(spec.Order[0])
            .ThenBy(spec.Order[1]);
    }
    else if (count == 3)
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(spec.Order[0])
            .ThenBy(spec.Order[1])
            .ThenBy(spec.Order[2]);
    }
    // And so on...
}
```

`Query`is an `IQueryable`, `spec.Order` is a list of clauses: `List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>`.

I know that I can use an OrderBy with all the clauses passed as string. And I guess I can just project all the `Order` clauses to a new string comma-separated. But that solution doesn't seem clean.

Is there any other way to dynamically generate one new `ThenBy` for every item of the `Order` list, above 1?

Comment: What is the type of `spec.Order`, exactly?

Comment: @Dai is a list of clauses `List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>`

Comment: Why dont you create an extension method and chain your calls:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497255/programmatically-chain-orderby-thenby-using-linq-entity-framework

Comment: @PraneetNadkar Im looking for exactly the opposite, that's why I'm using the specification pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop. Basically loop through all of the `Order` values, use `OrderBy` for the first one, and `ThenBy` for subsequent items. Since you've said that you're using `IQueryable`, I've modified this to use a temporary `IOrderedQueryable<T>` variable.

```
if (spec.Order != null)
{
    var count = spec.Order.Count;

    IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(spec.Order[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(spec.Order[i]);
        }
    }
    query = orderedQuery ?? query;
}
```

You could also approach it like this, although I'm not sure how the performance differs between the two methods, if it does at all:

```
if (spec.Order != null)
{
    var count = spec.Order.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (query is IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery)
        {
            query = orderedQuery.ThenBy(spec.Order[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.OrderBy(spec.Order[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, this was my first attempt, but didn't work. `Query` is an `IQueryable`. `ThenBy` expects and `IOrderedQueryable` so I can't just join them, nor cast them either.

Comment: @Erre can you add that information to your question, please?

Comment: @Erre What about this?